# How to find code source of scipy.special.rel_entr function?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-spatial

I am trying to look for the code source of [`scipy.special.rel_entr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.rel_entr.html#scipy.special.rel_entr) function in [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) but could not find `rel_entr` function definition.

I also tried to look in this code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6522/files#diff-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`scipy.special.rel_entr`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.special.rel_entr.html) is a [*ufunc*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html).  The core calculation that is used by the function is implemented in [Cython](https://cython.org/) in the file [`_convex_analysis.pxd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/_convex_analysis.pxd), specifically [these lines](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/ce4b43097356dfc42504d81d6164b73ee0896c71/scipy/special/_convex_analysis.pxd#L28-L36). All the wrapper code that implements the `ufunc` `rel_entr` is generated automatically when SciPy is built, based on configuration data in the file [`functions.json`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/special/functions.json).